# Adding a selected list entry to a new list entry

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I move the selected list entry by clicking button and move it to a new list entry

```
<pre className="reverse-list">
  {datas.map((data, i) =>
    <li key={i} className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex
     justify-content-between my-2">
     <div className="todo-icon">
       <span>
         <button></button>
       </span>
       </div>
         <h6 className="mt-2">{data.input}</h6>
           <div className="todo-icon">
             <span className="mx-2 text-success">
               <i className="fas fa-pen" onClick={()=>this.fEdit(i)</i>
                 </span>
                 <span className="mx-2 text-danger">
                   <i className="fas fa-trash" onClick={()=>this.fRemove(i)</i>
                 </span>
            </div>

    </li>
  )}
</pre>
```

Methods used

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      title: 'Todo List',
      act: 0,
      index: '',
      datas: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.refs.input.focus();
  }
```

**What should i add in the fcomplete method to get the required output?**

```
 fSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('try');

    let datas = this.state.datas;
    let input = this.refs.input.value;

    if(this.state.act === 0){   //new
      let data = {
        input
      }
      datas.push(data);
    }else{                      //update
      let index = this.state.index;
      datas[index].input = input;
    }



    this.setState({
      datas: datas,
      act: 0
    });

    this.refs.myForm.reset();
    this.refs.input.focus();
  }

  fComplete = (i) => {

  }

  fRemove = (i) => {
    let datas = this.state.datas;
    datas.splice(i,1);
    this.setState({
      datas: datas
    });

    this.refs.myForm.reset();
    this.refs.input.focus();
  }

  fEdit = (i) => {
    let data = this.state.datas[i];
    this.refs.input.value = data.input;

    this.setState({
      act: 1,
      index: i
    });

    this.refs.input.focus();
  }
```

I have tried using methods in fcomplete(). But I was not able to get the task done.I have added the complete code.
csccscsccs

csscscsccssc

Comment: you can change the datas list and add isClicked flag corresponding to each of the input (element of datas list). On every button click you can mark the corresponding isClicked flag to true. And then render 2 lists - one on the top whose isClicked is false and the other one on the bottom whose isClicked is true.

Comment: I can help you with the exact code too if you post the entire code here.

Comment: I have added the whole code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to display your list in such a way that the items marked as completed are displayed at the bottom of the list. My below answer is based on this assumption only.

Like I mentioned in the comments, you have to store your list in a different way:

```
fSubmit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('try');

    let datas = this.state.datas;
    let input = this.refs.input.value;

    if(this.state.act === 0){   //new
      let data = {
        id: (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1), // for generating random ids
        value: input,
        isComplete: false // you have to make this change here while creating the data item
      }
      datas.push(data);
    }else{                      //update
      let index = this.state.index;
      datas[index].input = input;
    }



    this.setState({
      datas: datas,
      act: 0
    });

    this.refs.myForm.reset();
    this.refs.input.focus();
  }


  fComplete = (id) => {
    // use id to update the list
    // use this in fEdit & fRemove
    const updatedDataList = this.state.datas.map(data => {
      if(data.id === id) {
        data.isComplete = true
      }
      return data;
    });

    this.setState({
      datas: updatedDataList
    });
  }
```

```
render() {
  const incompleteList = datas.filter(data => data.isComplete === false);
  const completeList = datas.filter(data => data.isComplete === true);
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

Display the two lists separately. (I don't understand your css classes, that you can see according to your design.) The idea is to display them in two separate lists to make it simple. Or otherwise you have to always modify your "datas" list and keep the incomplete list on top and append the completed data items at the end.

```
<pre className="reverse-list">
  {incompleteList.map((data, i) =>
    <li key={i} className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex
     justify-content-between my-2">
     <div className="todo-icon">
       <span>
         <button onClick={() => this.fComplete({data.id})}></button>
       </span>
       </div>
         <h6 className="mt-2">{data.input}</h6>
           <div className="todo-icon">
             <span className="mx-2 text-success">
               <i className="fas fa-pen" onClick={()=>this.fEdit({data.id})</i>
                 </span>
                 <span className="mx-2 text-danger">
                   <i className="fas fa-trash" onClick={()=>this.fRemove({data.id})</i>
                 </span>
            </div>

    </li>
  )}

  {completeList.map((data, i) =>
    <li key={i} className="list-group-item text-capitalize d-flex
     justify-content-between my-2">
     <div className="todo-icon">
       <span>
         <button></button>
       </span>
       </div>
         <h6 className="mt-2">{data.input}</h6>
           <div className="todo-icon">
             <span className="mx-2 text-success">
               <i className="fas fa-pen" onClick={()=>this.fEdit(i)</i>
                 </span>
                 <span className="mx-2 text-danger">
                   <i className="fas fa-trash" onClick={()=>this.fRemove(i)</i>
                 </span>
            </div>

    </li>
  )}
</pre>
```